# What is the MS_PerfDashboard schema in msdb?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, functions

We just migrated an old reporting server (running on 2005) to 2012 and some of the database performance monitoring jobs have started failing. I looked into them and found that they use a couple of functions in the msdb in a schema called MS_PerfDashboard, but the schema is missing on the new server. I had a quick browse online and found that people use this for performance monitoring, but what I couldn't find is where the functions came from originally. Are they part of an old SQL version? A plugin? Or just a script of functions that someone came up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the Performance Dashboad here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22602

From memory there is a setup.sql file which should recreate the objects for you.